# Proving $f\colon S \to S$; $f(x) = 1/x$ is bijective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Hey I'm trying to figure out this proof. I don't know if anyone could help but I would really appreciate it!

Let $S = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Prove that the function  $f\colon S \to S$; $f(x) = 1/x$ is bijective.

I understand that to prove that it is bijective, it has to be proven injective and surjective. Injective being one to one and surjective being onto.

Comment: Do you know what it means to be one-to-one or onto?

Comment: I think one to one is where only one value is assigned for one output, and for onto multiple values can be assigned to one output.

Comment: That isn't the most concrete answer... I would read over the definition of onto and one-to-one again

Comment: @graydad Updated my comment, is that more correct

Comment: @TrickyTycoon: Not really. You've not indicated any understanding of what "onto" means.

Comment: @graydad I read the definition of Unto and I am still confused, do you think you could clarify what onto means.

Comment: For sure: Onto means for every element in the codomain, you can find an element in the domain that maps to it. In the context of your problem, that means for every $y \in S$, there exists $x \in S$ such that $f(x) = y$

Comment: In elementary terms, onto means every conceivable (in $S$) value is achieved.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that $f$ is injective
Assume it isn't,  so $\exists$ two non equal elements $a, b\in S$ s.t $f(a)=f(b)$. So $1\over a$ $=$ $1\over b$ $\implies a=b$. Contradicting that $ a $ and $ b $ are unequal.

To prove that $ f$ is surjective. Choose any $r \in S$. Set $x$ to be s.t $1\over x$$=r$. Hence $x=$$1\over r$. Since $x$ is clearly in the domain of $f$, we have that $f$ is surjective.

Therefore $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Would the proof for injective be invalid because it assumes the conclusion?

Comment: In the proof for injection I let two values in the domain of f have the same value assigned to them by f. However, by simply rearranging f (a)=f (b), you get that this is only possible for when a=b. Sorry I should have mentioned that I rearranged the equation to get a=b

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Two easy steps:

1. $f(0,+\infty)=(0,+\infty)$ and $f$ is bijective on $(0,+\infty)$;
2. $f(-\infty,0)=(-\infty,0)$ and $f$ is bijective on $(-\infty,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is onto because if $r \in \Bbb R - \{0 \}$, then we want $r = 1/x$, so the points $x = 1/r$ precisely satisfies this property.

It is one-to-one because $f'(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2} < 0 \implies f$ is monotone.

Comment: I am a little confused on how it is one-to-one still, how does that imply that  *f*  is monotone?

Comment: No, I am saying it is one-to-one *because* it is monotone. You read it backwards.